# Заменить подстроку в строке

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется пользовательская строка "Hello World". Имеется маска "hello". Как произвести поиск по маске и обернуть найденный текст тегом `<b></b>`? Но обязательно сделать это не меняя регистра. Также нужно учитывать, что текст пользовательской строки может быть другим, в зависимости от предпочтений пользователя. Конечный результат работы должен быть таким: "**Hello** World", но не таким: "**hello** World".

Следующий вариант заменяет текст, но также изменяет регистр найденной подстроки(нежелательный эффект):

```
$text = "Hello World";
$mask = "hello";
$text = preg_replace("/".$mask."/iu", "<b>".$mask."</b>", $text);
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = 'Hello World';
$mask = 'hello';
$text = preg_replace("/($mask)/iu", '<b>$1</b>', $text);
echo $text;
```

Смотрите [результат](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a4743e455c8b49391d25d06d5bcf4bb1ca5180d7)

Единственное, если источник данных сомнительный, то стоит экранировать данные [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

А именно,

```
$mask = preg_quote($mask, '/');
```

Comment: Может быть стоит добавить `\b`? А то на строке `$text = "nehellow World";` результат может быть не совсем ожидаемым. Хотя у автора надо бы уточнить поведение в данном случае

Comment: @ВОРОН, Вариант предложенный `Romeo` работает вполне корректно. В случае со строкой `"nehellow World"` ведёт себя так, как нужно.

Comment: @StasHappy: ВОРОН в целом прав. Могут быть нюансы.

Comment: @romeo, да друг, я понял. Забыл также отметить, что маску я очищаю от нежелательных символов. Поэтому в моём случае, о нюансах можно не безпокоиться.